# Cannot invoke 'enumerate' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Getting an error "Cannot invoke 'enumerate' with an argument list of type '(String)' " when I'm following Neil North's game tutorial for iOS Swift. Is this relating to an old method of some sort in 1.2? Any ideas?

```
   convenience init(atlasName: String, tileSize: CGSize,
        tileCodes: [String]) {
            self.init(tileSize: tileSize,
                gridSize: CGSize(width: tileCodes[0].characters.count,
                    height: tileCodes.count))

            atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: atlasName)

            for row in 0..<tileCodes.count {
                let line = tileCodes[row]

                // ERROR IS HERE
                for (col, code) in enumerate(line) {
                    if let tile = nodeForCode(code) {
                        tile.position = positionForRow(row, col: col)
                        if tile.name == "scenery" {
                            tile.position = CGPoint(x: tile.position.x, y: tile.position.y - (tileSize.height/2))
                        }
                        addChild(tile)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: what is the data-type of variable line ?

Comment: @ogres,  that info is in the code: tileCode is type [String], line = tileCode[index], so line is of type String

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enumerate is unavailable call the enumerate method on the sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230761/enumerate-is-unavailable-call-the-enumerate-method-on-the-sequence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, String is no longer part of the collection type in swift 2.
You now want to use `line.characters`

For more reading on this matter, please see https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30

Comment: changed it to line.characters.enumerate(), worked great thanks!

Comment: I see you've inferred the solution from this answer while I was posting mine. Well done. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should call `enumerate` on the collection itself. But in Swift 2 `String` is not a collection anymore - it has a `characters` property instead.

So to iterate over your String you should call `enumerate` on the `characters` property:

```
for (col, code) in line.characters.enumerate() {
```