# Update enumerate function in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

Xcode says "'enumerate' is unavailable: call the 'enumerate()' method on the sequence"
When i try to use the new syntax

```
for (row, rowArray) in tilesArray.enumerate() {
```

Then the error pops up "Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'enumerate'"
What am i doing wrong?

```
init (filename: String) {
    if let dictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>.loadJSONFromBundle(filename) {
        if let tilesArray: AnyObject = dictionary["tiles"] {
            for (row, rowArray) in enumerate(tilesArray as! [[Int]]) {
                let tileRow = NumRows - row - 1
                for (column, value) in enumerate(rowArray) {
                    if value == 1 {
                        tiles[column, tileRow] = Tile()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enumerate is unavailable call the enumerate method on the sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230761/enumerate-is-unavailable-call-the-enumerate-method-on-the-sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously know that `tilesArray` is of type `[[Int]]`, so do the optional binding on the proper type

```
init (filename: String) {
  if let dictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>.loadJSONFromBundle(filename) {
    if let tilesArray = dictionary["tiles"] as? [[Int]] {
        for (row, rowArray) in tilesArray.enumerate() {
            let tileRow = NumRows - row - 1
            for (column, value) in rowArray.enumerate() {
                if value == 1 {
                    tiles[column, tileRow] = Tile()
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gosh, Im being so stupid today. But still theres the error after updating. 'enumerate' is unavailable: call the 'enumerate()' method on the sequence

Comment: For those of you coming for Swift 3 and later, it looks like the right method to use now is enumerated() instead of enumerate()